# Apache Camel single instance of a route running in cluster using database

Tags: apache-camel

I have Apache Camel application deployed on two servers and they consume from JMS endpoint. I want to make sure that only one camel route is consuming from jms endpoint at a time. The only option that I can use for clustering is using database as a lock store. Does Apache Camel provide such a feature?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to consume from a topic and not a queue.
On connection, use the same subscriptionName. Only the first connection will be allowed as far i know.

Comment: topic subscriptions even if shared using JMS 2.0 shared subscription spec results in load balancing of the messages between two competing consumers